# Generalized Pareto distribution (GPD)

Tags: machine-learning, order-statistics, extreme-value-theorem, extreme-value-analysis

I'm trying to understand the functional form of the Generalized Pareto distribution (GPD) presented in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution). In the "Definition" section location parameter $\mu$ does not appear in the function, whilst in the "Characterization" section it does. My question is:

1. how the GPD form presented in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution) can be reconciled with GPD form presented in other sources. (See pictures below). In the third picture, a sketch derivation of the GPD from the Generalized Extreme Value (GEV) distribution would suggest that $\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ should not appear in that form in the expression of the GPD as presented in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution).

*Picture 3* features an extract from [Extreme Value Modeling and Risk Analysis: Methods and Applications, Dipak K. Dey, Jun Yan](https://www.crcpress.com/Extreme-Value-Modeling-and-Risk-Analysis-Methods-and-Applications/Dey-Yan/p/book/9781498701297)

[**Picture 1.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8rgL.png)
[**Picture 2.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRswa.png)
[**Picture 3.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew3ox.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to read the article more carefully.  They are all the same.

Wikipedia begins by stating:

> It is specified by three parameters:  location $\mu$, scale $\sigma$, and shape $\xi$.  **Sometimes it is specified by only scale and shape and sometimes only by its shape parameter.**

(Emphasis mine.)  Then in the Definition,

> The **standard** cumulative distribution function (cdf) of the GPD is defined by $$F_\xi(z) = \begin{cases} 1 - (1+\xi z)^{-1/\xi}, & \xi \ne 0 \\ 1 - e^{-z}, & \xi = 0. \end{cases}$$

The use of the word "standard" in this context is analogous to the way we call $Z = \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 0, \sigma = 1)$ a **standard** or **standardized** normal distribution; i.e., the location parameter is zero and the scale parameter is unity.

The article proceeds to generalize the above (again, as we do with the normal distribution) by replacing $z$ with $(x-\mu)/\sigma$ with location $\mu$ and scale $\sigma$.  This three-parameter family is the same as what we see in your attached images, after accommodating for the emphasized sentence above.

Comment: That's great! many thanks @heropup. The last thing I still find confusing in Picture 3 is that $\mu$ appears in the GEV distribution and during derivation of GPD it disappears from numerator, and appears in the denominator. Can we just re-introduce it again to generalize GPD? Are the $\mu$'s the same in GEV and GPD?

Comment: @Alex  No, they are not the same $\mu$.  As you can see, they postulate from Equation 1.1 the existence of a parameter vector $\theta$ that fixes a $\mu$, $\sigma$, $\xi$ such that the following approximation for $F^n (z)$ holds.  Then the conditional survival distribution is generalized Pareto, with shape $\xi$ and scale $\sigma_u$, and location $0$, with respect to the variable $y$.